# Question:Is this hotel selling cigarettes?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

I am confused with this question:

"Is this hotel selling cigarettes?" or
"Does this hotel sell cigarettes?"

"Is this computer working?" or
"Does this computer work?"

Which one is correct? Is there any other way of saying it?

Comment: You may find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) useful.

Comment: What @jwpat said. Leyla - native speakers don't use present continuous in the first example (which must be plural "cigarettes" anyway), because hotels either do or don't sell cigarettes *all the time*. But with the computer example, either is possible. It's largely the difference between *"Is this computer working **now**?"* and *"Does this computer work **at all**?"*

Answer (score 1):

All of those sentences are correct.

However, for the first example, a native English speaker would probably **not** say "Is this hotel selling cigarettes?".  The hotel probably either sells cigarettes or does not. But that wording makes it sound like you are asking "Is this hotel currently selling cigarettes *right now*?". With that wording, it may be a valid question, but it's probably not what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, I would choose "Are cigarettes sold at this hotel?"

Either choice for the second question is fine.